# JavaScript d3.js save graph when leaving site

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a little zoom and scrollable scatterplot. I want to be able to click on items and get redirected to a website. When i hit the back button i want the graph to display the exact same thing it showed when i clicked the button. At the moment it just goes back to the default view.

I tried to save the state of my x axis, which apparently works, like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("minDate", xScale.domain()[0]);
localStorage.setItem("maxDate", xScale.domain()[1]);
```

However, i'm not sure how to go on from here. I tried setting it manually when i update my view, but that doesn't do anything

```
   if(tempMaxDate != null && tempMinDate != null) {
        xScale.domain()[0] = tempMinDate;
        xScale.domain()[1] = tempMaxDate;
    }
```

[Here's a link to my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkt7ssqz/)

Changing the domain seems to be the wrong way, i think i'll just try to focus it on the dot i clicked and translate to that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `window.beforeunload` event to save the `translate` and `scale` values of the zoom/drag state of the `plotChart`  Then you can apply them when the page is next loaded, else you revert back to default values.

See code below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem("myScale", myScale);
    localStorage.setItem("myTranslateX", myTranslate[0]);
    localStorage.setItem("myTranslateY", myTranslate[1]);
};

var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20
},
width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


window.myScale = 1;
window.myTranslate = [margin.left, margin.top];

if (localStorage.getItem('myScale') !== null) {
    myScale = localStorage.getItem('myScale');
}

if (localStorage.getItem('myTranslateX') !== null && localStorage.getItem('myTranslateY') !== null && (localStorage.getItem('myTranslateX') !== 0 && localStorage.getItem('myTranslateY') !== 0)) {
    myTranslate = [localStorage.getItem('myTranslateX'), localStorage.getItem('myTranslateY')];
}

var currentDate = new Date();
var minDate = new Date().setMonth((currentDate.getMonth() - 5));
var maxDate = new Date().setMonth((currentDate.getMonth() + 2));

var plotChart = d3.select("body").classed('chart', true).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
var myZoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scale(myScale).translate(myTranslate).on("zoom", redraw);
plotChart.call(myZoom)
    .append('g');

var plotArea = plotChart.append('g')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#plotAreaClip)');

plotArea.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'plotAreaClip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
    width: width,
    height: height
});


//x and y axis
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 4])
    .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(height)
    .orient("top");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .ticks(4)
    .tickSize(width)
    .orient("right");

plotChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
var gy = plotChart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

gy.selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -30)
    .attr("dy", -4);

plotChart.append('rect')
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0);

if (myTranslate != [0, 0]) {
    plotChart.attr('transform', "translate(" + myTranslate[0] + "," + myTranslate[1] + ")" + " scale(" + myScale + ")");
}

function redraw() {
    plotChart.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    myScale = d3.event.scale;
    myTranslate = d3.event.translate;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wnrmjrc9/

Answer (score -1):

Hey You can use onbeforeunload event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp